# Preventing RDP from logging off administrator

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote

I have two users on my WindowsServer2016, one is Administrator, and the other is UserRDP.
I want remote users to access via RDP to UserRDP but not to Administrator, and I have already done this using group policies.
Now if I can connect to UserRDP but I can't connect to Administrator, but the problem is that the Administrator still gets disconnected if someone tries to connect via RDP.
What I want to do is to have access to UserRDP via RDP, but have no access to Administrator and prevent RDP from disconnecting Administrator remotely

Comment: Is UserRDP a member of the local administrators group? This link indicates that a normal user does not have the *Disconnect* right https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753032(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: the announced Situation is totally normal due the fact that Windows allows only 1 connection without Terminal Server. either buy CAL and license them or live with this restriction...